# What do we know about black hole and its existence?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics

Yesterday, I had an exchange with my colleague about a black hole. His theory was that black holes were merely an imaginary construction that is purported to have some mathematical meaning. Is what he said true? If not, how do we know about black holes' existence and what properties do we know about them?

Comment: You search info on black holes. There is even a picture of one.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole

Comment: We've taken a picture of one. If that doesn't make you believe it's not imaginary, I don't know what will.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Direct observations of a black hole?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29696/)

Comment: Though the linked duplicate has also been answered in several other questions that provide the evidence for for the existence of black holes. e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/409/

Comment: Maybe your colleague thinks that you are merely an imaginary construction in his/her head, and of course black holes are just made up by made-up people. If not, then he/she ought to apply the same epistemic standards to the existence of black holes as he/she does to the existence of you.

Answer (score 1):

We mostly know about black holes from theorizing But here’s an image of one proving its existence.
https://physicsworld.com/a/first-images-of-a-black-hole-unveiled-by-astronomers-in-landmark-discovery/

Comment: Physicists have also measured the gravitational waves emitted when black holes merge.

Comment: @G.Smith Yes and studies large stars orbiting black holes.

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

We know that there are things that behave like a black hole should behave.  As an example of this, in the center of most or all galaxies there is a massive object that seems to have the mass of thousands or millions of times the mass of our sun. We don't know of any other objects that could have that much mass.  Likewise, these objects behave like we think that black holes should behave with things such as massive accreation disks, etc.  We don't believe that much mass can accumulate that way except for it being a black hole.

Comment: thats a very satisfying answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your colleague was right a few years ago but since the detection of gravitational waves he isn’t any more. Here is why.

When Ptolemy proposed his geocentric model he still thought that the planetary orbits where perfect circles. Circles where the mathematical model of that time for the orbits.

When the measurements of the orbits became more precise (by Tycho Brahe I think) it was noticed that the circle model is not valid.  Kepler introduced ellipses as the new model and Newton delivered the explanation, deriving the ellipses model from the inverse square law of gravity.

Newton’s model kept being valid until it was noticed that Mercury’s orbit does not quite match it. Einstein’s new model of general relativity explained Mercury’s orbit very well. In addition, it offered the possibility of the existence of black holes.

No physicist thinks that Einstein’s model is the final answer because it has some major flaws, e.g. mathematical singularities in black holes, which are meaningless for physical reality. Quantum Gravity is currently considered the way out but no complete model exists yet.

However, concerning the existence of black holes one crucial question was open: does the model of general relativity break down before black holes can form or not? This is one of the big deals about the discovery of black hole mergers with LIGO: it proved that indeed the mathematical model of general relativity matches real observation in the sense that black holes *do* exist.

So the answer is: our current  mathematical model is consistent with the observations; black holes do exist.